Method or Data Member not found This is my code
I'm stuck on this problem and I could really use some help finding where I went wrong. I've checked my work a dozen times, but I just can't seem to spot the mistake. Any ideas or suggestions would be super appreciated. Let's solve this puzzle together!
This is the code:
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    Dim Customer_ID As String
    Dim Customer_Name As String
    Dim Address As String
    Dim Contact_info As String
    
    Customer_ID = Me.txtCustomer_ID.Text
    Customer_Name = Me.txtCustomer_Name.Text
    Address = Me.txtAddress.Text
    Contact_info = Me.txtContact_info.Text
    
    If Customer_ID = "" Or Customer_Name = "" Or Address = "" Or Contact_info = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter all the needed info."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Check if the connection is established
    If ConnectToDatabase Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Connection to the database is not established."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Execute SQL query to check if the course already exists
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Customer_ID='" & txtCustomer_ID.Text & "'", ConnectToDatabase
    
    ' Check if the query returned any records
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        MsgBox "customer already exists. Please choose a different Customer ID."
        rs.Close
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Close the recordset
    rs.Close
    
    ' Execute SQL query to insert the new course record
    Dim insertSQL As String
    insertSQL = "INSERT INTO customer (Customer_ID, Customer_Name,Address,Contact_info) VALUES ('" & Customer_ID & "', '" & Customer_Name & "','" & Address & "','" & Contact_info & "')"
    ConnectToDatabase.Execute insertSQL
    
    MsgBox "Successfully saved!"
    
    ' Clear text boxes after successful registration
    Me.txtCustomer_ID.Text = ""
    Me.txtCustomer_Name.Text = ""
    Me.txtAddress.Text = ""
    Me.txtContact_info.Text = ""
    frameCourse.Enabled = False
    frameSave.Enabled = False
    frmMain.Enabled = True
End Sub


Let's solve this puzzle together! - the only puzzle here is on which line the error happens, which is not a puzzle we should be solving because you already know the answer.

So where are you declaring and setting the ConnectToDatabase ConnectionString and opening the connection?
Other than that, where's your error handling?
And don't exit the sub from the middle.  do your procedure cleanup before you exit..
(OK.. so everyone's got an opinion...)
The real answer is, that the ConnectToDatabase has no meaning in this code. it's not defined anywhere.
1st your declare ADO in your references.. 

Then declare the DB Connection AND a ConnectionString in your code BEFORE you attempt to use the ConnectToDatabase.. something like this.

And make sure you're using the correct ServerName, DatabaseName, UserID and password.. OR you can set IntegratedSecurity=True and leave out the UserId & Password and your windows credentials will be used to connect to the db..
And what I said about the error handler and exit sub still apply.. There are methods to write clean functional VB6 code... Check out MZ Tools.
If you're gonna do VB6, do it well.

This is not an answer to the question, rather this is a comment.

And where do opinions go?

It's pretty clear from the code that ConnectToDatabase is supposed to be defined elsewhere, and is checked to be valid in the presented method. It could not cause the error in question either.

"And where do opinions go?" In the comments of the question, as opposed to posting as an Answer.
